# How to store an array to the cache in Symfony?

Tags: php, caching, symfony4

I have an array to display from database and after many business implementations which is taking time of 1~2 minute to get me final output. So this process is annoying me while testing with UI. So I decide to store this final array into the cache. I have tried following lines of code to store `myArray` into cache.

```
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;
use Symfony\Contracts\Cache\ItemInterface;

$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
// The callable will only be executed on a cache miss.
$output = $cache->get('my_cache_key', function (ItemInterface $item) use ($myArray) {
    $item->expiresAfter(7200);

    return $this->serializer->provideSerializer()->serialize($myArray, 'json');
});
```

I think when read from cache should be faster but it is still taking the same time to load data.

Can anybody please help me how can I store my array to the cache so next time it will be faster to load.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You should put $myArray data retrieval into your callback as per [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_pools.html#using-the-cache-contracts) and **do not pass** it in through `use` because that means its retrieval is done outside of cache run cycle. It is mentioned on line 11 that heavy computation should occur (or, in your case, lengthy database retrieval of the value) inside the callback.

In your case it should be like so

```
$output = $cache->get('my_cache_key', function (ItemInterface $item) {
$item->expiresAfter(7200);

// Your lengthy database query that retrieves data to be cached
return $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(MyClass::class)
    ->find($id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the following: json_encoding the array and then, decoding it into an array when I retrieve it from cache. - seems to work for me, but relatively inexperienced with caching at this level though

Anyone see any issues with this approach?

For context: this is used to manually provide Choices for a TextField I created in easyadmin 4.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

// ... inside the HotelCrudController 
use App\Manager\HotelManager;
use App\Entity\Hotel;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ChoiceField;

class HotelCrudController  extends AbstractCrudController
{
    // .. other code
    protected HotelManager $hm;


    public function __construct(HotelManager $hm)
    {
        $this->hm = $hm;
    }

    public static function getEntityFqdn() : string
    {
        return Hotel::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        // ... other fields
        yield ChoiceField::new('Room', 'Zone')
            ->setChoices($this->hm->getRoomChoices())
            ->autocomplete();

    }

    // ...

}
```

Here's the code with the cached data.

```
<?php 

//... 

    public function getRoomChoices()
    {
        $data = $this->cache->get('room_choices',  function (ItemInterface $item): string {
            $item->expiresAfter(3600 * 8);
            $response = $this->hotelFinder->getTableData(HotelClient::HOTEL_CODE);
            $result = [];
            foreach($response as $row) {
                $data = $row['attributes'];
                $result[$data['room_type']] = $data['room_type'];
            }
            return json_encode($result);
        });
        return json_decode($data, true);
    }

// ...

?>
```